# Failed to run react-native link on my project

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native link` on my RN project, I got below error:

```
$ react-native link
rnpm-install ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure it's a React Native project?

Cannot read property '_text' of undefined
```

I have searched that some people say run `react-native upgrade` will resolve this issue. I have tried but no lock. My react version is shown as below:

```
$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.39.2
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is not a solution to your prblm its an alternative. Try npm install rnpm -g and rnpm link. See if it links your packages

Comment: I already tried rnpm but it doesn't work as well. I wander why link got `_text` undefined error.

Comment: Try upgrading RN to latest version(0.42.3 as of now) with react-native-git-upgrade. See if it helps

Answer (score 4):

Follow below steps in order -

1. `npm cache clean` or `yarn cache clean`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `yarn install` or `npm install`
4. `react-native upgrade` ( You can choose no in all steps)
5. `react-native link`

If you get permission related error use `sudo` with all commands.

Comment: `sudo npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 3):

A little late but this may help someone else. My problem was large commented out copies of `<manifest> ... </manifest>` in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. Once I removed commented out copies, link worked as expected.

It seems `xmldoc` had touble parsing the manifest even though the AndroidManifest.xml was valid XML. Calling `react-native link` uses `../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/android/index.js`. To debug such issues in future I would start with putting debugging statements in `../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/android/index.js` and narrow down to the root cause of the issue. Similar logic should work for ios.

Answer (score 3):

For me cleaning the gradle did the trick.

1- Go to the root directory of the project.

2- Run `cd android`

3- Run `gradlew clean`

4- Run `cd..`

and then run the `link` commands

Answer (score 3):

i had this problem. i fixed it with following way:

1- edit `"/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml"`

2- add `package="com.YOUR PACKAGE NAME"` inline `manifest` tag. like:

`<manifest package="com.YOUR PACKAGE NAME"`

note: replace `"YOUR PACKAGE NAME"` with your package. you can find it in "/android/app/src/**main**/AndroidManifest.xml"

3- cd android

4- ./gradlew clean

5- cd ../

6- react-native link

Answer (score 1):

try to go android -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml and delete all comments here. After that rerun react-native link, and all is working for me. Good luck!